# Reading data from multiple nodes in cassandra parallelly across nodes

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using cassandra version 3.11.3 and I have created cassandra cluster of 2 nodes in my local machine.

I am creating a spark job(Java) that consumes data parallelly from all Cassandra nodes.

I am using below setup to get my TokenRange Set for my cluster
Keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test_keyspace WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 }


private static Host getLocalHost(Metadata metadata, LoadBalancingPolicy policy) {

    Set<Host> allHosts = metadata.getAllHosts();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    Host localHost = null;
    for (Host host : allHosts) {
      if (policy.distance(host) == HostDistance.LOCAL) {
        localHost = host;
        break;
      }
    }
    return localHost;
  }

  public static TokenRange[] getTokenRangesAcrossNodes() {

    Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    Host localhost =
        getLocalHost(metadata, cluster.getConfiguration().getPolicies().getLoadBalancingPolicy());
    return unwrapTokenRanges(metadata.getTokenRanges("test_keyspace", localhost))
        .toArray(new TokenRange[0]);
  }

  private static Set<TokenRange> unwrapTokenRanges(Set<TokenRange> wrappedRanges) {
    Set<TokenRange> tokenRanges = new HashSet<>();
    for (TokenRange tokenRange : wrappedRanges) {
      tokenRanges.addAll(tokenRange.unwrap());
    }
    return tokenRanges;
  }
```

So, as per the above setup, I was assuming I will get 2 TokenRange when I call method `getTokenRangesAcrossNodes`, as I have 2 nodes. But instead I got 256. Then, I did some reading on vnodes, so I assume its token ranges of multiple vnodes. Further, when I use replication factor as 2, I get 512.

My first question is how did this 256 or 512 TokenRange is decided?

Secondly, through my job if I query all these token ranges parallelly, wouldn't it be possible that many ranges don't return any result and I end up querying for no result in most cases? Isn't it better to get token ranges specific to nodes instead of vnodes?

Last question, If I want to get the token range of nodes(not vnodes), what change I need to make in above setup?